# Restrict mobile app users to a particular country

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, react-native, google-play

I am developing mobile app using react native. I am using Amazon AWS as back-end.

My question is how do I restrict users to a particular country? That is, I want people from only one country may use my mobile app.

I have released my app on google play store and there I have made a selection to make my app available in a particular country. But I want to be more strict. I want to  have some more checks maybe in my client code or back-end AWS server code where I can check for country.

For more information, I am using the following Amazon AWS services for my mobile app: AWS S3, AWS lambda etc. Is there some code that I can write here using which I can restrict mobile users to a particular country? What are other elegant ways?

Comment: Unfortunately i think you can't, you can try to check based on IP address, but today many use VPN and you can't trust the IP anymore.

Comment: Not really.  You could do it on the front end by checking the location.  But on the back end the best you could do is look at the IP, which is not a 100% thing.  Also, if the app is available in the US and stops working when I go to Canada for vacation, I'd be pissed.  I really wouldn't suggest doing this unless its a legal issue.

Comment: Your issue is more of a business, rather than a technical, issue. Depending on why you want to restrict, you may simply want to add a label stating this app applies only to X country. There may be some mechanism in AWS as well.

Comment: The restriction within the App Store or Play Store should be sufficient. I believe the app does not show in the store for users outside the country scope.  However, many users use VPN's as mentioned above so becomes difficult then. 

If you are using CloudFront on AWS, there is Geographic Restrictions that you can apply.

Comment: You can use AWS WAF to protect API Gateway-backed APIs, including blocking requests that originate from a specific country or region.